# Do I have to throw out soil in a pot that had snails on the turmeric?

Tags: soil, containers, herbs, potting-soil, snails

I had snails in the pot with my turmeric. I threw the infested plants away but left the soil as I have ginger sprouting in the same pot.

Do I have to throw the soil out?

Comment: coffee grounds and snails don't mix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNjPKwjvLhk

Comment: Are you still using coffee grounds as if it was plant GOLD?  Been around long enough to know that coffee grounds LOOK GOOD but what a joke.  The only substance plants love is soil with lots of decomposed organic matter.  DECOMPOSED.  pH adjusted, or accounted for depending on specific needs of specific plants.  Diatomaceous  earth is a good deterrent

Comment: Trap snails and slugs with lager beer traps. They work beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

No - just treat for snails; snails and slugs are always with us, everywhere, more noticeably in damp weather, so regular applications of slug and snail repellents are usual. Snails are easier to deal with, you can pick them off by their shells anyway.

Comment: Really just picking snails off, getting the pot more difficult to climb into...go out at night and pick the snails off.  Slug and snail bait I've never had any luck at all using and I no likey that stuff is bad for pets and other animals.

Comment: I have no qualms about using metaldehyde pellets - the trick is to be very sparing and not use enough to make the soil look blue, a sight I often see here in the UK.

Comment: hey there Bamboo, you don't have kitties or dogs?  And I agree, that blue slime is gaggy.  Grins.  How fast do slugs and snails die after eating these pellets?  Do they have enough time to slime home? Grins.  I always have animals up the kazoo...

Comment: Used to have cats, still used the pellets, cats were fine, even the kittens... dogs sre more risky, but only if they eat half the pack... I was more worried about birds eating poisoned slugs, but RSPB says there's no evidence

Comment: Grins, what birds have you got that eat slugs?  I used to have muscovi ducks that ADORED slugs and slugs were very common Pacific Northwest.  I am still kinda in the Pacific Northwest but high dry desert.  My ducks loved to poop out these slugs on my back door stoop.  Unbelievably gross.  Otherwise, I've no problems with slugs here in the high and very dry desert...we just had a major freeze the last two nights.  We are moving when we get the chance...but I'll have to show you our new greenhouse, not covered as yet.  That would be hard to leave...

Comment: Oh I just mean wild birds, lots of 'em eat slugs and snails